# Executing OS Commands from Spring Shell

Tags: java, spring, unix, vi, spring-shell

I'm using

```
org.springframework.shell:spring-shell-starter:2.0.0.RELEASE
```

With gradle and Spring

My question is:
Is there anyway to open vi or vim to edit a file in the OS from the shell?. if not what alternatives do I have to edit this file?

Regards

James

Answer (score 1):

I m not pretty sure with Spring, but with in Java you can, using `ProcessBuilder` and moreover it will help you to execute multiple command sets.

Quick look: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-lang-processbuilder-class-java/

Comment: Thanks, I considered that alternative,but I know that Spring Shell 1.0 provides a notation with "! command" to execute a command, but I cannot make it work in 2.0